# Andriod Build failing due to com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.2 depends on one or more Android Libraries

Tags: android, gradle

In my CI pipeline until June 6 it worked.  Today it failed. The following build error occurred.

WARNING: Module 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.2' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
 A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 > Could not find support-vector-drawable.jar (com.android.support:support- 
vector-drawable:26.0.2).
Searched in the following locations:
  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-vector- 
drawable/26.0.2/support-vector-drawable-26.0.2.jar



   Build.Gradle file

    buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.4"
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.+'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
     }
   allprojects {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://mobile-sdk.jumio.com' }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com/" // Google's Maven repository
    }
    maven {
        url  "http://kochava.bintray.com/maven"
        }
      }
    }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
   }   



       App level 

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
    apply plugin: 'newrelic'
     apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

   android {
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.seven.eleven.phoenix"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 16
    versionName "1.1.1_1_QA"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    renderscriptTargetApi 21
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
  sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 
     'src/main/assets/fonts'] } }

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'STRIPE_APIKEY', 
   keystoreProperties['StripeKey']
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'PHOENIX_API_KEY', 
   keystoreProperties['PhoenixAPIKey']
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'NEW_RELIC_KEY', 
    keystoreProperties['NewRelicKey']
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY', 
    keystoreProperties['OpenWeatherAPIKey']
    it.buildConfigField 'int', 'WORKING_BRANCH', getCurrentGitBranch()

           }
      }

      def getCurrentGitBranch() {
  def gitBranch = "Unknown branch"
   try {
    def workingDir = new File("${project.projectDir}")
    def result = 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'.execute(null, workingDir)
    result.waitFor()
    if (result.exitValue() == 0) {
        gitBranch = result.text.trim()
    }
  } catch (e) {
   }

   if(gitBranch.contains('master')||gitBranch.contains('PROD') || 
    gitBranch.contains('7XXX_Master')){
    return "1";
} else {
    return "0";
}
 }

  ext {
SDK_VERSION = "2.10.0"
ANDROID_VERSION = "26.0.2"
       }

  repositories {

     mavenCentral()
     }

  dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', 
  {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
        }
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
        }
compile group: 'de.mindpipe.android', name: 'android-logging-log4j', 
version: '1.0.3'
compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'

compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${ANDROID_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:${ANDROID_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:${ANDROID_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.android.support:design:${ANDROID_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${ANDROID_VERSION}@aar"

compile "com.jumio.android:core:${SDK_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.jumio.android:bam:${SDK_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.jumio.android:nv:${SDK_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.jumio.android:nv-mrz:${SDK_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.jumio.android:nv-barcode:${SDK_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.jumio.android:nv-barcode-vision:${SDK_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.jumio.android:nv-liveness:${SDK_VERSION}@aar"
compile "com.jumio.android:dv:${SDK_VERSION}@aar"


compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
compile group: 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber', name: 'libphonenumber', 
version: '7.0'

compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}

compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
 compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}

compile files('libs/simple-xml-2.7.1.jar')


compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.kochava.base:tracker:3.2.0'
compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.+'

compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.0.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

//for pay with google using google wallet service
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'

compile 


compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-kms:2.6+') { transitive = true; }
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.6.1"
      }
      dependencyManagement {
       imports {
    mavenBom 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.257'
  }
   }

   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have included the build gradle file as well as app level project configuration  It was unable to download that dependency.Any help would be greatly appreciated.we are using an gradle 4.1 and a docker container to make the build. I used command ./gradle clean initially.

Comment: Please post your app level and project level gradle

Comment: @Debanjan I updated the question. Any  suggestion would be greatly appreciated.